# My code does not execute

Tags: vba, excel

I run the following code and VBA just flashes for a millisecond and no results are given. No matter how I edit the code, VBA would not execute it.

I am so confused. However, if I run my original code, it works...I try making the same edits to my original code and VBA would run but would stop running after a few tries.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on?

Start Code:

```
Sub LeadDetailsQR()

    Dim OgData As String
    OgData = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets(OgData).AutoFilterMode = False
    varMyData = Sheets(OgData).Range("AK2", Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

        For Each varItem In varMyData
            If Not IsEmpty(varItem) Then .Item(varItem) = Empty
        Next varItem

        For Each varItem In .keys

            Cells.AutoFilter
            Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(varItem).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            ActiveSheet.Name = varItem
            Sheets(OgData).Select
            Sheets(OgData).Range("AK1").AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:=varItem
            Sheets(OgData).Cells.CurrentRegion.Copy
            Sheets(varItem).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Sheets(OgData).Cells.CurrentRegion.Copy
            Sheets(varItem).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        Next varItem

    End With

    Sheets(OgData).AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Orginal code (works):

```
Sub LeadDetailsQROriginal()

    Dim OgData As String
    OgData = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets(OgData).AutoFilterMode = False
    varMyData = Sheets(OgData).Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each varItem In varMyData
            If Not IsEmpty(varItem) Then .Item(varItem) = Empty
        Next varItem
        For Each varItem In .keys
            Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = varItem
            Sheets(OgData).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=varItem
            Sheets(OgData).Select
            Sheets(OgData).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            Sheets(varItem).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
            Sheets(OgData).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            Sheets(varItem).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Next varItem
    End With

    Sheets(OgData).AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code to see where it's failing. We can't do that for you, because we don't have your worksheet.

Comment: When posting code, please take some time to *indent* it - you're more likely to get help if your code is easily readable.  A big block of left-aligned code is difficult to scan.

Comment: @KenWhite There is no error code/bug that returns. The worksheet stays the same.

Comment: That's exactly why I said **step through the code in the debugger**, where you can see what's happening with each line of the code. Again, we can't do that for you. Stepping through it line by line lets you see which lines are actually executing (and which aren't), inspect the values of variables to make sure they contain what you expect, and see if you have logic errors in your code.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean and I do step through the code in the debugger (F8) but **none** of the code is actually running. Not a single line.

Comment: Sounds like a hidden stuck Excel.exe is in the way. Save and close your file and exit Excel. Launch task manager and End Process for any Excel.exe. Finally launch Excel and open that file again.

Comment: @Zeta - Are you saying that, even with a break-point on `OgData = ActiveSheet.Name`, that that line of code isn't running?

Answer (score 2):

I am embarrassed to say that I have found the answer. The code is doing exactly what it is doing. It ran without error because the range it was looking for is blank and as a result, nothing is created.

If I am not being clear, let me explain the code. The code is supposed to create a new sheet based on each unique value in a column. The code ran without producing any results because I was asking the code to look at column AK, which is a blank column. So of course it didn't produce anything :)